# Reading file stream multiple times causes "stream not readable" error

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-blob-storage, moq, filestream

I'm trying to mock a read operation by using file stream in unit test. Below is the simplified code in application.

```cs
using (var stream = await client.OpenReadAsync())
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        // read a line
        record = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
    }
}
```

This is the mock

```
var client = new Mock<Client>();

//return file stream when read is performed on mocked client
client.setup( c => c.openReadAsync()).ReturnAsync(File.Open("c:\\testFile.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
```

This works well when the stream is read for the first time. I have a logic where the same stream is read second time based on a condition. So the code above for reading stream is repeated in another place and it throws "stream not readable" error.

My understanding is whenever the client.OpenReadAsync() is called, a new file stream should be returned based on the mock condition. How do I fix this ? Can I use any other stream to overcome this ?

**Update**:

Based on Matt's suggestion, the below code for first read makes the second read works well, but client.OpenReadAsync() and stream reader are not closed, which I'm not sure cause any issues

```
  var stream = await client.OpenReadAsync()
  using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream,**leaveOpen: true**))
    {
             // read a line
             record = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
    }
```

The openReadAsync() reads from Azure storage. During the actual run everything works fine. In the actual run , the client returns this [stream](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/e72578a830248ab524d614754010a3eb21a90d4d/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Blobs/src/BlobBaseClient.cs#L3148). Probably, if I find a way to mock the same stream, things might work.

Comment: It happen because of stream position. When you read first time its position goes to end. And you have to move it back to 0 for second or more read. Some stream types are not allow second time read. You have to read about streams from official docs.

Comment: @RaminQuliyev I understand the file stream goes to end. But in actual execution of application , this issue doesn't arise. I have added more details above on the stream returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you're returning the same task each time your mock is called - you're calling `File.Open` *once*, and returning that same task every time `client.OpenReadAsync` is called.

I suspect you just need to move the call into a lambda expression:

```cs
client.Setup(c => c.OpenReadAsync())
      .ReturnAsync(() => File.OpenRead("c:\\testFile.txt"));
```

(You may need to tweak that a bit - you didn't provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and we don't know which version of Moq you're using, so it's hard for me to test the exact syntax you'll need - but the principle is that you need to open the file separately on every call.)

Comment: @DxG - In case you're wondering what "mcve" means (I did), here's a possible explanation: [What is the acronym MCVE?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367019/1016343)

Comment: @Matt: Whoops - hadn't realized that [mcve] wouldn't work in the post. Doh. Will edit the actual link...

Comment: Great. That was the issue. Changing it to lambda did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading a stream, it tracks the read position. If the end is reached but you're trying to read further, you're getting an error.

Make sure that you set the read position to 0 before you read it again, like

`stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);`

You can try a pattern like

```
using (Stream stream = await client.OpenReadAsync())
{
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        // read a line
        var record = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
        // ...
        // close the reader when you're done reading
        reader.Close();
    }
    stream.Close();
}
```

**Note:** After discussing this with [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet), we came to the conclusion that the behaviour you have observed is a bug (details see below in the comments). Opening a "fresh" stream should always start at position 0.

Hence, this is a workaround - you should analyze the issue further to find out where the root cause is.

Update: In this particular case, Jon found that the unwanted side effect is coming from the mock setup which doesn't seem to create a fresh stream every time and hence the read position isn't being reset properly.

You're very welcome to let us know what you found out and update us on your testing.

Comment: This is working only if I leave the stream open while reading for the first time by removing using() and then apply stream.Seek(0, SeekLocation.Begin). Now the second time read works well. But is it a good practice to keep the stream open ?

Comment: Added more details on the actual stream returned which do not cause this issue.

Comment: @DxG - I have updated my answer. Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: "Notice that you can safely place the seek statement at the begin, before you start reading." There's no need to do that. The stream returned by `File.Open` is always at the start. "It is a good practice to close the stream when you're done reading, because the using statements only take care of the dispose and might leave the operation in a weird state" - no, `Dispose` is all you should need for a stream or reader. It will flush automatically if needed.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Ok, I removed this paragraph from my answer. But why is DxG having these issues then? I remember I had also issues in a project with an ExcelReader that required a seek to position 0 - without it you couldn't read a second time. So I got to the conclusion that while in theory a `using` should be enough in practice it is not always the case.

Comment: @Matt: Looking again, I believe it's because the mock is being setup incorrectly. It should be set up to call `File.Open` each time, whereas currently it's only calling it once. But the change shouldn't be to the *production* code, because it's reasonable to assume that `client.OpenReadAsync` will return a fresh stream.

Comment: (If you find a stream that doesn't dispose properly when you call `Dispose`, that's a bug in that stream. I'd need to see the precise example to see if there's a different problem though.)

Comment: @JonSkeet - Yes I agree, it is most likely a bug and re-opening a Stream should always start to read at position 0. One of the examples where you need a workaround because you're not in the position to fix the bug of the imported component.

Comment: Your edited answer doesn't really note that the bug is in the OP's code... it's in how they've set up the mock to return the same stream on every call, instead of creating a *new* stream on each call.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Thanks for the hint, I have updated my answer. I hope it describes it better now.

Comment: Well sort of - but I'd personally still avoid the advice of "rewind to the start of the stream just in case, and explicitly call Close just in case Dispose doesn't work properly". (As an aside, I normally just use `position.Stream = 0;` as a simpler way of rewinding anyway.) If you removed that advice, you'd basically end up repeating/referencing my answer. It's entirely up to you whether you keep this answer or not, but *personally* I don't think it's adding value right now.